# Curious case of efficiency of equation algorithm, why are more operations faster?

Tags: c#, performance, calculation, processing-efficiency

I lately wrote a bit that shall smooth out the extends of a 0-1 range. Out of curiousity I measured the performance of two possibilities to acchieve the same end result. What came out is that this:

`_ = (Mathf.Sin(-1.57079633f + (time * 3.14159265f)) + 1) * 0.5f;  // Sin + 4o`

faster than this

`_ = Mathf.Cos(time * 3.14159265f) * -0.5f + 0.5f; // Cos + 3o`

even though the former has more operations?
And it's not faster by just some tiny bit, it's approximately 31% faster.
For time `t` a constant of 0.5f was used.

There's no difference in using Sin or Cos for either, I did test for that in case the algorithm behind those functions would be the cause.
Since `Mathf` is a Unity thing i tested it using `System.Math.` as well to make sure this isn't the cause, the results are roughly the same exept that `System.Math.` is overall a tiny bit slower since it calculates a double that then has to be cast to a `float (Single)`.

Is Someone able to enlighten me why this is the case? I'd be interessted in undestanding why this is.

Addendum: Testing code

```
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
{
    _ = (Mathf.Sin(-1.57079633f + (time * 3.14159265f)) + 1) * 0.5f; // Sin + 4o
}
sw.Stop();
print($"Sin calc time = {sw.ElapsedTicks * 0.0001f}ms ({sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms)");
sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
{
    _ = Mathf.Cos(time * 3.14159265f) * -0.5f + 0.5f; // Cos + 3o
}
sw.Stop();
print($"Cos calc time = {sw.ElapsedTicks * 0.0001f}ms ({sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms)");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Mathf` is a Unity thing, not a .NET thing

Comment: You're right, edited it so it is mentioned. Tested it as well to exclude the possibility and used System.Math, the results are the same.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at the IL generated by each.

Comment: `For time t a constant of 0.5f was used.` Do you mean that you had something like `const float time = 0.5f;`? If not, what *do* you mean?

Comment: Other than order of operations I can't really see a diference there. I don't see into `[System.Runtime]System.Math::Cos(float64)`/`[System.Runtime]System.Math::Sin(float64)` though.

Comment: Did you just run them once each or did you run them many times and then use the average times?

Comment: @Matthew Watson All three possible scenarios; I directly defined `0.5f` within the algorithm, I used a defined `const float time = 0.5f` and I used a regular field value. Same results in all cases.

Comment: @YungDeiza I used a 500k itteraion for loop

Comment: When using a `const` value of 0.5 for time, the .NET 7 compiler (and presumably earlier versions too) pre-calculates the parameter to pass to `Math.Sin()` and `Math.Cos()`. For the call the `Math.Sin()` this ends up calling `Math.Sin(0)` - and I suspect that the implementation of `Math.Sin()` has an optimisation for that case that just returns 0.

Comment: @MatthewWatson the logic is sound but why const is relevant? The value passed to Sin is 0 in any case, whether time is const or not.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You're absolutely right, I didn't think of that. Tested again and assigned a random value to `time` before starting the loop, this makes them about equivalent. Makes perfect sense since then the former is only one operation plus whatever happens in `Sin()`.

Comment: @Evk Because if it's being calculated, it changes the timings so that the proportional difference in time between the two calls is a lot lower

Comment: Also I suspect that you are running this in Debug, try Release configuration with optimizations. Because I suspect it can be heavily optimized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a value of `0.5` for `time`, the call to `Math.Sin()` ends up calling `Math.Sin(0)` - and I suspect that the implementation of `Math.Sin()` has an optimisation for that case that just returns 0.

The value passed to `Math.Cos()`, however, will be ~`1.5707963705062866`, and it's likely that this will NOT have a similar optimisation.

The fact that your `time` value was `const` also means that the compiler can pre-calculate the values passed to `Math.Sin()` and `Math.Cos()` which means that it doesn't matter if the calculation for `Math.Sin()` contains more operations, since they will not be performed at run-time.